# about what to write on a text.bat in order to overload(not sure about that) my computer to crash

Tags: batch-file, text

A couple years ago i watched a video on youtube on how to make my computer overload and crash with a 4-line text file made into a .bat because my brother would come to my room and turn the pc on and wake me up every single time, the only problem is, i can in no way remember which exact lines were written on the text and neither i can find the video which indicated those lines. The characeristics of the subject were as follows: it was a .bat file which when you doubled clicked on it it would pop up a command prompt window which would almost immediately render any interaction with the displayed icons on the desktop impossible, and after a 10 second period it would cause the mouse to make more sharp edged movements and after a while of lets say a minute or so it would make my main wallpaper background covering my desktop to get all black and dissappear while slowly incapacitating the whole pc and making it unusable like it wasnt working properly, sort of like turning off the "explorer"..

The only main components that i can bring back to memory are:

@echo off

something like "start"

-//-

-//-

goto "something"

...There wasnt anything like 0% or any other characteristic numbers or codes, only simple words.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the video you were talking about:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8ASUgrSh5ic

If you make a batch file and inside you start an infinite number of something the computer run out of resources and will kill itself.  for example in the video they start cmd.exe an infinite number of times:

```
@echo off
:here
start cmd
goto here
```